# how to extract data from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, data-extraction

First-time poster, long time struggler.

I am trying to extract data from a list made up of dataframes originally imported from `.asc` files. I need to extract several rows of data from one or more columns of all the files.

I can extract a single row column using the `sapply` function but am having trouble extracting multiple rows from the same column across the data that makes up the list. I have tried to look at the posts dealing with this, but can't find the solution.

set working directory

```
setwd ("C/....")
```

bring in `.asc files (4,032 files, [80R, 48C] each)`

```
temp <- list.files (pattern = "*.asc")
```

create object

```
myfiles <- lapply (temp, read.delim, header = False, skip = 6, sep = "")
```

check format (worried about importing .asc files)

```
print(myfiles)
```

structure is fine no NAs and aligned

single row,column from all files

```
sapply(myfiles, function(x) x[35,14])
```

Up to here, this works fine, I get exactly what I want--an indexed output of all values

```
 [1] 13  10  25  37  48  46  38  45  41  35  28  15  26

[14] 48  13  41  37  32  24  25  28  32  41  29  28  27
```

I could now create a new line of code for each row 36 to 42 in column 14 for what I need, like:

```
sapply(myfiles, function(x) x[36,14])
sapply(myfiles, function(x) x[37,14])
sapply(myfiles, function(x) x[38,14]), etc. to
sapply(myfiles, function(x) x[42,14])
```

but I figure I should be able to extract these at once and export them as a .csv file. My looping attempt failed as I get all the data for every column and every row for the entire list. Also, could I add a different series to this for example [52:62, 18:24] and export each?

```
data1 <- sapply(myfiles, function(x)
{
x[35:42, 14] 
return(x)
})
```

Any suggestions? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try `sapply(myfiles, function(x) x[36:42,14])` ?

Comment: yes, I tried this earlier, and  also variations involving  '[' and didn't have any luck--this actually has output of [,1] [,2] [,3] up to my file limit of [,4032]. Basically, an index of the number of my files the function is looping through.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select multiple columns, you can use [dplyr::select](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/select). For example, the code below will get you both columns 1:3 and columns 7:10, and rows 1:2. I do not know a way to select multiple rows.

```
sapply(myfiles, function(x) dplyr::select(x[1:2,], 1:3, 7:10))
```

Comment: this throws up an error: Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : position must be between 0 and n. Might this be because I am working on a list rather than a dataframe?     sapply(myfiles, function(x) dplyr::select (x[35:42], 14))

Comment: I forgot the comma after row selection, just fixed it.

Comment: Super your fix above works, and I have a csv output file, but it's all mixed up mixing columns and rows, but the data is there. Thank-you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your workflow by using `purrr::map_dfr()`, this would give you a single dataframe containing all the extracted data from files (a more appropriate object to write to a csv file)

```
library(tidyverse)

setwd ("C/....")
list_of_files <- list.files (pattern = "*.asc")


df <- list_of_files %>%
    setNames(nm = .) %>% 
    map_dfr(~{read.delim(.x, header = FALSE, skip = 6, sep = "") %>% 
            .[35:42, 14] %>%
            enframe()},
            .id = "file_name")
```

Comment: Just gave this a try and it works very well. I am unfamiliar with 'piping' but it works well, and the output has a better form to work with. Thank-you for your help.